# bottom bar layout with selected box?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml, android-menu, bottomnavigationview

I am developing an android application.

I developed this thing

[image]

But I need to develop a box behind the selected Menu item like this.

This I need

[image]

I hope you help me to develop this.

This is my code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="project.andromeeda.testproject.MainActivity">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/replace"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:background="#ddd"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/navigation"
        app:itemBackground="@drawable/list"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/grey"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Now its shows only background color without text or icon.

Comment: show your xml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `selector` drawable to `app:itemBackground` in xml .

Below is an example .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@color/red" android:state_checked="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/gray"/>
</selector>
```

Inxml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:itemBackground="@drawable/item_selector"
    ></android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>
```

Modify the selector as per your need . and make multiple selector. a Normal for below API21 inside drawable . drawable-v21 for API21 above.

Comment: I tried it. But the icons are hidden and displays only the background colour after clicking the item.